# No spacing between buttons with bootstrap 3.x what could be the issue?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently following an Angular course on Udemy, when I typed as exactly as the instructor, I am not getting any space between buttons but the instructor has it just fine in the video, even when I import the instructor's code, same thing happens. What could be the issue?

[This is instructor's video screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYdax.png)

[This is Screenshot of when I deploy it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXs15.png)

I haven't made any changes to the code so it doesn't make sense as to why is this happening. Facing across multiple browser as well.

Comment: are you sure that the version, you are using is the exact one that the instructor used in the tutorial?

Comment: yeah I tried using the one in the video and even newer version, still got the same result.